# TensorFlow image reading queue empty

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, computer-vision

I'm trying to use the pipeline for reading images to the CNN. I used `string_input_producer()` to obtain the queue of file names, but it seems to hang there without doing anything. Below is my code, please give me some advise of how to make it work.

```
def read_image_file(filename_queue, labels):
    reader = tf.WholeFileReader()
    key, value = reader.read(filename_queue)
    image = tf.image.decode_png(value, channels=3)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    resized_image = tf.image.resize_images(image, [224, 112])
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        label = getLabel(labels, key.eval())
    return resized_image, label

def input_pipeline(filename_queue, queue_names, batch_size, num_epochs, labels):
    image, label = read_image_file(filename_queue, labels)
    min_after_dequeue = 10 * batch_size
    capacity = 20 * batch_size
    image_batch, label_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
        [image, label], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=1, capacity=capacity,
        min_after_dequeue=min_after_dequeue)
    return image_batch, label_batch

train_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(trainnames, shuffle=True, num_epochs=epochs)

train_batch, train_label = input_pipeline(train_queue, trainnames, batch_size, epochs, labels)

prediction = AlexNet(x)

#Training
with tf.name_scope("cost_function") as scope:
    cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=train_label, logits=prediction(train_batch)))
    tf.summary.scalar("cost_function", cost)

    train_step = tf.train.MomentumOptimizer(learning_rate, 0.9).minimize(cost)

#Accuracy
with tf.name_scope("accuracy") as scope:
    correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(prediction,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
    accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))
    tf.summary.scalar("accuracy", accuracy)

    merged = tf.summary.merge_all()

#Session
with tf.Session() as sess:
    print('started')
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord, start=True)
    sess.run(threads)

    try:
        for step in range(steps_per_epch * epochs):
            print('step: %d' %step)
            sess.run(train_step)
    except tf.errors.OutOfRangeError as ex:
        pass

    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is not completely self-contained as the `get_label` method is not defined.

But it is very likely that the issue you have comes from these lines in the `read_image_file` method:

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    label = getLabel(labels, key.eval())
```

The `key.eval` part tries to dequeue an element of a queue which has not started yet. 
You shouldn't create any session before your input pipeline is defined (nor try to eval `key` (and possibly `labels`)). The `get_label` method should only perform tensor operations on `labels` and `key` and return a `label` tensor..

For example, you can use these [`tensor` string operations](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_guides/python/string_ops) so they will be part of the graph.

Comment: I defined `getLabel` in my code but didn't attach it here, it basically extracts the label from the file name (a string), but key is a tensor. So I did `key.eval()` to get the string of the file name. Now it seems not working, is there another way to get the string from the tensor?

Comment: You probably need to replace all your string operations by string tensor operations, so they will be part of the graph and will be executed at runtime.

Comment: I cannot open the website of tensorflow for some unknown reasons. Do you know what operations I can use to extract the label from the string tensor?